# Call to undefined function oci_connect only from cli (works fine in html)

Tags: php, linux, apache, command-line-interface, oracle-call-interface

**Environment:**
**Server**: Ubuntu Server 12.04 x64
**Web Server**: Apache 2
**PHP**: 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
**Oracle**: Instant Client 11.2

Problem:
I have a script that I am setting up as a cron job, but when it runs it produces

> PHP Fatal error; Call to undefined function oci_connect() in /var/www/reports/inc/config.php on line 25

If I run this script or any other script using oci_connect or oci_pconnect through Apache, they work fine. I just migrated to a new machine and the script ran fine on the previous machine, but I cannot think of what I am missing.

Permissions on the script are the same as the config file and I have tried running as www-data, my user account, and root (all provide the same error).

Comment: Sounds like you haven't configured the OCI extension in the `php.ini` file for the CLI version.

Comment: Barmar, that did it! I didn't even think to check the /etc/php5/cli/php.ini folder since everything else I do with PHP is handled by /etc/php5/apache/php.ini

Comment: @Barmar you should use your comment as an answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

You have to specifie the user custom profile file (.bash_profile or .profile) before launching the script

> 0 7 * * * . $HOME/.bash_profile; php -e -c /etc/php.ini /var/www/html/script_avec_oci.php

Answer (score 0):

When you use PHP from the shell or `crontab`, you're using the CLI version, not the webserver version, and they usually have separate `php.ini` files. Edit `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and enable the OCI extension.